# Core data fetch request with GROUP BY

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, core-data

I have a table in my application which consists of some names and phone numbers and orderIDs and dates (4 columns).
I want to get an array of all distinct phone numbers (Note that someone with a phone number may have several orderIDs).

Test case: suppose that this is the current records of my table.

`Name    phoneNumber    orderID    date
John     1234           101        2014-12-12
Susan    9876           102        2014-12-08
John     1234           103        2014-12-17`

I want an array of distinct phone numbers only, something like: {1234, 9876}
How can I perform such a fetch in core data?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

P.S: As I knew in SQL I could do something like:

`SELECT phoneNumber FROM orders
 GROUP BY phoneNumber`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Distinct](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp) Keyword. so your query will become

```
SELECT DISTINCT phoneNumber FROM orders
```

Comment: Thank you but I wanted to know how to implement that in Objective C using CoreData.